# Timing the blit of an enemy list in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Outside of my game loop, I have created a function that creates a list of 200 enemies with random coordinates. These enemies are suppose to start at the top of the screen and then drop down at random speeds. Inside the loop, I use a "for" loop to blit the enemies on screen. It works, but all 200 hundred are spawned and fall at the same time, albeit, at different speeds. So I know I need a timer and herein lies the problem; nothing I do works. Ive tried `clock.tick()`, `pygame.delay()`, `import time` and do the `time.time()` method. Everything either strobes or the system just crashes. What's causing the problem?

[Code]

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import time

pygame.init()
        
#MAIN GAME

game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Beer Goggles")

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
bg_image = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (600, 600))

class Object:

    def __init__(self, image_path, width, height, x, y):

        self.image_path = image_path
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        player = pygame.image.load(image_path)
        self.player_main = pygame.transform.scale(player, (width,height))

    def draw(self, background):

        background.blit(self.player_main, (self.x, self.y))

#enemies

def enemy():

    enemy_list = []

    for e in range(200):

        x_cor = random.randint(25, 361)
        
        e = Object("enemy.png", 70, 70, x_cor, 25)
        enemy_list.append(e)

    return enemy_list

#Main Objects
        
player1 = Object("crate.png", 70, 70, 25, 500)
list1 = enemy()

#ladies
fat_lady = Object("fat_lady.png", 300, 300, 360, 180)

# Main Loop

direction = 0

game_on = True

while game_on:

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_on = False
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                direction = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = -1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = 0

    game_screen.fill((0,0,0))
    game_screen.blit(bg_image, (0,0))

    #title.draw(game_screen)
    player1.draw(game_screen)
    fat_lady.draw(game_screen)

    #move

    if direction > 0:
        player1.x = player1.x + 10
    elif direction < 0:
        player1.x = player1.x - 10

    #boundaries

    if player1.x <= 25:
        player1.x = 25
    elif player1.x >= 360:
        player1.x = 360

    #for enemy in list1:

    for enemy in list1:
       a = random.randint(1, 30)
       enemy.draw(game_screen)
       enemy.y += a
    
    #collisions

    #scoring
       
    pygame.display.update()

quit()
```

Comment: Please format your code. You can format it by indenting everything by 4 spaces or by marking the code and pressing the `{}`-button in the editor

Comment: I edited away the _"Stack Overflow wasn't at all helpful"_ as you generally get less people inclined to help you when you tell them that they aren't helpful, especially when all of your questions have been edited and answered by helpful people here on Stackoverflow. Also, I'd recommend you to tick the answers you've got in previous questions as accepted (**if** they solved your problem), as it'll mark the question as answered and give the one who answered points for their time and effort.

Comment: Thank you Ted, really didn't mean to be rude with the "helpful" statement, just frustration with my lack of understanding... you wouldn't happen to have a solution for me would you?

Answer (score 1):

In the code where you create the `enemy` list you could add a drop start time. Just like you create a random x co-ordinate you could create a time to start dropping it. Then later when you start changing the y position for them (dropping them), you would not start it dropping until after that time had passed.

By the way You have a method `enemy()` and later you have a loop iterator `enemy` which will override hide the method by that name. After that point if you tried to call the method `enemy()` it would fail and you would access the loop iterator instead. It does not affect your code here because you do not try to access the method after creating the loop iterator variable, but it is not a great idea and could cause problems if you later changed the code and did try to access that method. You should be careful about name choices.

Comment: Thank you Glenn, how would I got about creating a "drop start time" in the function?

Comment: There are a variety of ways. The basic idea is that you generate a random delay amount 
 to delay the start time by for each  of the enemy objects. I assume since you are using random already that you can manage that. Then you want to use that as an offset from the game time. You can get the game time by using `pygame.time.get_ticks()` (see docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks)). You should be able to figure it out from there.